# OpenDKIM mail header: temperror

Tags: ubuntu, postfix, dovecot, opendkim

I've just installed and configured OpenDKIM to use it with Postfix and Dovecot on my server. I can send e-mails to another accounts, but when I check the header I find this:

```
dkim=temperror (no key for signature)
```

Here is the most important configuration I made (in fact, I followed [this tutorial from DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-dkim-with-postfix-on-debian-wheezy)). My server is running Ubuntu 14.04 (x86).

In fact, how can I correct that error? (The line tells me that the mail isn't verified).

---

#### File: /etc/opendkim.conf (fragment)

```
AutoRestart             Yes
AutoRestartRate         10/1h
UMask                   002
Syslog                  yes
SyslogSuccess           Yes
LogWhy                  Yes

Canonicalization        relaxed/simple

ExternalIgnoreList      refile:/etc/opendkim/TrustedHosts
InternalHosts           refile:/etc/opendkim/TrustedHosts
KeyTable                refile:/etc/opendkim/KeyTable
SigningTable            refile:/etc/opendkim/SigningTable

Mode                    sv
PidFile                 /var/run/opendkim/opendkim.pid
SignatureAlgorithm      rsa-sha256

UserID                  opendkim:opendkim

Socket                  inet:12301@localhost
```

---

#### File: /etc/opendkim/TrustedHosts

```
127.0.0.1
localhost
192.168.0.1/24
*.fjweb.club
```

---

#### File: /etc/opendkim/KeyTable

```
1115._domainkey.fjweb.club fjweb.club:1115:/etc/opendkim/keys/fjweb.club/1115.private
```

---

#### File: /etc/opendkim/SigningTable

```
*@fjweb.club 1115._domainkey.fjweb.club
```

---

#### File: /etc/default/opendkim

```
SOCKET="inet:12301@localhost"
```

---

#### File: /etc/postfix/main.cf

```
milter_protocol = 2
milter_default_action = accept
smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:12301
non_smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:12301
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the problem, and may be silly, but I'll leave it here so anyone can check this first:

**Remember to double-check not to add the domain next to the host value of the TXT record**

What I mean is this: OpenDKIM needs a TXT record (check DNS settings for the domain you have) to succesfully sign e-mails. Check the "Name" (or "host") column of it: that sould be `default._domainkey` and *not* `default._domainkey.yourdomain.bla`!